# Apache Camel CVE-2019-0188 Exposure

Tags: security, apache-camel

`Apache Camel prior to 2.24.0 contains an XML external entity injection (XXE) vulnerability (CWE-611) due to using an outdated vulnerable JSON-lib library. This affects only the camel-xmljson component, which was removed.`

This description specifically mentioned the camel-xmljson component. Our organization uses automated scanning tools to detect vulnerabilities in open source libraries -- it is currently flagging all application with Apache Camel dependencies < 2.24.0 including the applications that do not contain any version of camel-xmljson. I'm trying to determine if that is the correct exposure. Is there any exposure to the XXE attack if the application is not including camel-xmljson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exposure at all, its *only* if you use the `camel-xmljson` component, where that 3rd library JAR has the security vulnerability (eg its not really Camel but the 3rd party JAR itself).

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought. As the maintainers of the libraries is there anything in the CVE disclosure you can update to reflect that the affected jar is only the camel-xmljson jar so our automated tooling doesn't flag everything camel? I'll work with our vendor (Black Duck) to see if there is anything on their side they can do as well.

Comment: Its this old jsonlib JAR that has the problem: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.23.2/components/camel-xmljson/pom.xml#L46 and https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.23.2/parent/pom.xml#L417